# SQLite3 - library routine called out of sequence using iOS 7

Tags: ios, sqlite, sequence

Using a shared instance I have sometime a crash during the execution.

Crash can be reproduced but never happen in a regular way. Such crash appeared using iOS 7.0 was working properly with previous iOS release.

Help will be welcomed

```
2013-11-26 12:25:38.149 Publilex[1942:a0b] library routine called out of sequence
2013-11-26 12:25:38.229 Publilex[1942:a0b] Uncaught exception Failed to open database with message 'library routine called out of sequence'.

2013-11-26 12:25:38.261 Publilex[1942:a0b] Stack trace: (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01ef05e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01bc48b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x01ef03bb +[NSException raise:format:] + 139
    3   Publilex                            0x00027097 -[DBAccess raiseSqliteException:] + 199
    4   Publilex                            0x00023c3d -[DBAccess open] + 173
    5   Publilex                            0x00023ae8 +[DBAccess shared] + 232
    6   Publilex                            0x00027e5e +[Word synIdForWord:] + 78
    7   Publilex                            0x0002812d +[Word synIdsFor:] + 429
    8   Publilex                            0x00037b8b -[Searcher nbArticlesFor:] + 187
    9   Publilex                            0x0002df2b -[SearchViewController updateSuggestionsFor:] + 731
    10  Publilex                            0x0002e5ef -[SearchViewController textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:] + 783
    11  UIKit                               0x00e0fa56 -[UITextField keyboardInputShouldDelete:] + 252
    12  UIKit                               0x008ff0f7 -[UIKeyboardImpl callShouldDeleteWithWordCountForRapidDelete:characterCountForRapidDelete:] + 691
    13  UIKit                               0x00909ed5 -[UIKeyboardImpl deleteFromInputWithExecutionContext:] + 84
    14  UIKit                               0x00906965 -[UIKeyboardImpl handleDeleteAsRepeat:executionContext:] + 130
    15  UIKit                               0x0091516f -[UIKeyboardImpl handleKeyWithString:forKeyEvent:executionContext:] + 633
    16  UIKit                               0x00914cb6 -[UIKeyboardImpl handleKeyEvent:executionContext:] + 1808
    17  UIKit                               0x0091450f __33-[UIKeyboardImpl handleKeyEvent:]_block_invoke + 51
    18  UIKit                               0x00e371b8 -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue continueExecutionOnMainThread] + 402
    19  UIKit                               0x00e3785f -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue addTask:] + 144
    20  UIKit                               0x009144d4 -[UIKeyboardImpl handleKeyEvent:] + 227
    21  UIKit                               0x0073dfbb -[UIApplication _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 330
    22  UIKit                               0x00884634 -[UIResponder(Internal) _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 59
    23  UIKit                               0x00884634 -[UIResponder(Internal) _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 59
    24  UIKit                               0x00884634 -[UIResponder(Internal) _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 59
    25  UIKit                               0x00884634 -[UIResponder(Internal) _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 59
    26  UIKit                               0x00884634 -[UIResponder(Internal) _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 59
    27  UIKit                               0x00884634 -[UIResponder(Internal) _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 59
    28  UIKit                               0x00884634 -[UIResponder(Internal) _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 59
    29  UIKit                               0x00884634 -[UIResponder(Internal) _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 59
    30  UIKit                               0x00884634 -[UIResponder(Internal) _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 59
    31  UIKit                               0x00884634 -[UIResponder(Internal) _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 59
    32  UIKit                               0x00884634 -[UIResponder(Internal) _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 59
    33  UIKit                               0x00884634 -[UIResponder(Internal) _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 59
    34  UIKit                               0x0073de6a -[UIApplication handleKeyUIEvent:] + 84
    35  UIKit                               0x0073de0e -[UIApplication handleKeyHIDEvent:] + 458
    36  UIKit                               0x00725c8c _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2954
    37  CoreFoundation                      0x01e798af __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    38  CoreFoundation                      0x01e7923b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
    39  CoreFoundation                      0x01e9630e __CFRunLoopRun + 910
    40  CoreFoundation                      0x01e95b33 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    41  CoreFoundation                      0x01e9594b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    42  GraphicsServices                    0x02ef49d7 GSEventRunModal + 192
    43  GraphicsServices                    0x02ef47fe GSEventRun + 104
    44  UIKit                               0x0072a94b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    45  Publilex                            0x00002893 main + 115
    46  libdyld.dylib                       0x0246e725 start + 0
)

+(DBAccess *)shared{
    @synchronized(self){
        if (sharedInstance == nil){
            sharedInstance = [[DBAccess alloc] initWithFileName:DATABASE_NAME];
            [sharedInstance createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded];
        }
        [sharedInstance open];
    }
    return sharedInstance;
}

- (NSArray *) executeSQLNoCache:(NSString *)sql{

    NSLog(@"%@ - Execution No Cache", sql);

    char* errorMessage;

    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSMutableDictionary *queryInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
    [queryInfo setObject:sql forKey:@"sql"];

    NSMutableArray *rows = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    sqlite3_stmt *statement = NULL;
    int returnCode = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sql UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL);

    if (returnCode == SQLITE_OK) {

        BOOL needsToFetchColumnTypesAndNames = YES;
        NSArray *columnTypes = nil;
        NSArray *columnNames = nil;

        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            if (needsToFetchColumnTypesAndNames) {
                columnTypes = [self columnTypesForStatement: statement];
                columnNames = [self columnNamesForStatement: statement];
                needsToFetchColumnTypesAndNames = NO;
            }

            NSMutableDictionary *row = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            [self copyValuesFromStatement:statement
                                    toRow:row
                                queryInfo:queryInfo
                              columnTypes:columnTypes
                              columnNames:columnNames];

            [rows addObject:row];
            [row release];

        }

    } else {
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);

        [self raiseSqliteException:
         [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Failed to execute statement : '%@' with message: ", sql] stringByAppendingString:@"%S"]];
    }

    [queryInfo release];
    sqlite3_exec(database, "COMMIT TRANSACTION", NULL, NULL, &errorMessage);
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);

    [pool release];
    return rows;
}
```

Comment: Since the exception was out of `open` it would be nice to see the source for that.

Comment: Sorry, just seen your reply.

As you can see below the log, you have the shared instance code and the execution of my SQL request without cache.

The code was working properly using iOS 6, but now, I got unexpected crash which can be reproduced but not with a specific action or time of usage.

Comment: So you're not going to give us any clues as to what was going on in DBAccess?

Comment: I give you all clues, just let me know what information you need

Comment: What was going on in DBAccess?????????????????????

Comment: Could you please clarify your question … DBAccess is called every time i do a sql request to check if the shared instance is open or not. If it's not open, I open the DB. So, at a certain stage, the DB get out of sequence with a request, while it should check if the instance is open … let me know what you need exactly and will provide you all info.

Comment: You have an exception in DBAccess.  Examine the source there and see what happened at the point of the exception.  If necessary, rerun the test and step through the routine to see what's happening.

Comment: Most strange, is that it was not happening with iOS 6 … I have  a raise exception in my code, but not exception are raised, just the out of sequence. I already step over without success ...

Comment: This is linked with the shouldChangeCharactersInRange which is sometime called twice when I hit a character on the keyboard you can check the issue here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20353191/shouldchangecharactersinrange-call-twice

Comment: So you refuse to show us the code where the exception is actually occurring?

Comment: (Most likely you're trying to open a DB instance that is already open.  `shared` will (foolishly) open the instance every time it's called.)

Comment: It's why DB Access os there and check if the instance is open or not. If open, it return the pointer to the opened instance. So it should never happened and was not happening with iOS 6 8O(((

Comment: So where does it check if it's open?

Answer (score 0):

Here, the code to run all statements without SQL Cash. and the only error raised is library run out sequence :

```
- (NSArray *) executeSQLNoCache:(NSString *)sql{

    NSLog(@"%@ - Execution No Cache", sql);

    char* errorMessage;

    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSMutableDictionary *queryInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
    [queryInfo setObject:sql forKey:@"sql"];

    NSMutableArray *rows = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    sqlite3_stmt *statement = NULL;
    int returnCode = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sql UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL);

    if (returnCode == SQLITE_OK) {

        BOOL needsToFetchColumnTypesAndNames = YES;
        NSArray *columnTypes = nil;
        NSArray *columnNames = nil;

        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            if (needsToFetchColumnTypesAndNames) {
                columnTypes = [self columnTypesForStatement: statement];
                columnNames = [self columnNamesForStatement: statement];
                needsToFetchColumnTypesAndNames = NO;
            }

            NSMutableDictionary *row = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            [self copyValuesFromStatement:statement
                                    toRow:row
                                queryInfo:queryInfo
                              columnTypes:columnTypes
                              columnNames:columnNames];

            [rows addObject:row];
            [row release];

        }

        sqlite3_reset(statement);

    } else {
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);

        [self raiseSqliteException:
         [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Failed to execute statement : '%@' with message: ", sql] stringByAppendingString:@"%S"]];
    }

    [queryInfo release];
    sqlite3_exec(database, "COMMIT TRANSACTION", NULL, NULL, &errorMessage);
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(database);

    [pool release];
    return rows;
}
```